# MongoDB Save does not remove pre-existing elements

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a strange situation with a MongoDB Save (C# driver).  I am saving an existing document (the key is in-place within the BsonDocument being saved).  My Save statement looks like this:

```
SafeModeResult result = moleculeCollection.Save(moleculeDoc, SafeMode.True);
```

where moleculeDoc is a BsonDocument.  The elements within the moleculeDoc BsonDocument being saved can vary.  Sometimes elements in the existing document within the database will be removed because the moleculeDoc BsonDocument being saved no longer contains them.

The trouble is, after a successful Save some of the elements remain within the database-held doc, even though they did not exist within the BsonDocument being saved.  When I save a SECOND time then these elements typically disappear.

I have carefully eye-balled the BsonDocument in detail prior to the Save, and it definitely does not contain certain elements that appear after the Save (but which did exist within the database-held doc prior to the Save.

Here is an example of a Saved doc:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$binary": "qAvZU8AzqES1fv0OL9GaBw==",
    "$type": "03"
  },
  "title": "Url 1a",
  "mediatype": "url",
  "modifieddate": "Wed, 09 Nov 2011 11:56:57 GMT",
  "filename": "iphone.pdf",
  "contenttype": "application/pdf",
  "weburi": "ffff"
}
```

Note that the "filename" element was NOT within the BsonDocument that was saved, yet it remains in place after the Save, having been in the database prior to the Save.

One strange aspect is that it does remove these 'ghost' elements after a SECOND Save.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I am sure that mongodb save is an upsert( document level rather than field level as in update). It will override the whole document if the id exists or create new one. so whatever fields in new doc only be there in the saved documen.. what is the type of moleculeCollection?? is it MongoCollection?

Answer (score 0):

Save completely replaces an existing document with a new one or inserts a new document if no existing document is found. The behavior you are describing should not be possible.

If you can supply a reproducible case please create a JIRA ticket for this at jira.mongodb.org.

Also, I notice you are using a UUID as your _id value. For historical reasons different drivers have used different byte orders when saving UUIDs in the database (so the binary values are different). In particular, the mongo shell and the C# driver don't use the same byte order so you might not be looking at the same documents.